# Is it possible to fetch the name attribute value from this XML using SQL query

Tags: sql, xml

I have a table named Person having column name Message which has XML data.
"<Name name="George", Id="123" />"
Is it possible to fetch the name attribute value from this XML using SQL query.

Comment: Yes we can, but please tag the database you are using

Comment: I am using RDBMS, and the below query i am using:

select message fro Person where message like '%name%';

But i dont know how to fetch only name's value

Comment: What date base are you using?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @JimMacaulay already asked you few times: What is your database? Is it MS SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, or something else?

Comment: It is MySQL only

Comment: Hi @JimMacaulay any suggestion?